# По клику на html-блок сложить сумму чисел в этом блоке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется 3 карточки. В каждой карточке число.
Нужно по клику на каждую карточку сложить сумму этих чисел.
Это как в интернет магазине, когда выбираешь кучу товаров.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: имеется 3 карточки... а код имеется?

Answer (score 4):

Вот, предлагаю такой вариант:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".block")].forEach(block => {
  block.addEventListener("click", () => {
      block.classList.toggle("active");
      document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = `Сумма чисел в выбранных блоках: ${count()}`;
  })
});

function count() {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll(".block.active")]
               .reduce((a, e) => a + +e.innerHTML, 0);
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 300ms;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: arial;
  
}

.active {
  background-color: wheat;
  border-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">-1</div>
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
</div>
<div id="result">Выберите блоки</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('div').click(function() {

  var all_count = Number($('.count').text());
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
    var count = Number($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.count').text(count + all_count);
  } else {
    var count = Number($(this).text());
    $('.count').text(all_count - count);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<span class="count">0</span>
```

Comment: я кликнул на 1 и добавил  1. А как сделать чтоб при повторном клике отнять 1

Comment: @SiarheiMlynchik отредактировал код